# Rewrite sequence $\frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^n}}$ in the form $a_n - a_{n+p}$ where $p \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> For arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace -1, 1\rbrace$, how can one rewrite the sequence $\frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^n}}$ in the form $a_n - a_{n+p}$ where $p \in \mathbb{N}$?

The ***background*** is the following: We were able to proof, that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n - a_{n+p}) = \left( \sum_{n=1}^p a_n \right) - pa$, where $a_n \to a$.

So for instance $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1$, since with $a_n := \frac{1}{n}$, I find $\frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$ and $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as well as $\sum_{n=1}^1 \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1$.

So if we could rewrite the original sequence in this form, we would be able to find the limit of the series.

Comment: So you want to find $a_n$ such that $a_n-a_{n+1}=\frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^n}}$

Comment: @Amr I think he means $a_n-a_{p+n}=\displaystyle\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^n}}$

Comment: @user10444 I doubt this as the RHS is not a function of $n$

Comment: @Amr: Close. I want to find $a_n$ such that $a_n−a_{n+p}=\frac{x^{2^n}}{1−x^{2^n}}$ with some $p \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Amr My fault I forgot to place $\sum$ before the left side

Comment: @mjb I believe there is no elementary function with this property

Comment: I edited the original post to state the example more clearly.

Comment: @Amr I could not find one as well, but this is an exercise from a german book.

Comment: @mjb wow. There might be a way to evaluate the infinite sum

Comment: @mjb I can find such a function $a_n$ if you were asking about $\frac{x^{2^n}}{1+x^{2^n}}$

Comment: @Amr Yes, but the exercise states, that it should be done that way. Anyhow: I would not have any other idea to find the limit of this sum.

Comment: @Amr ok. maybe it's a misprint in the book. how would you do that?

Comment: @Mjb Are you sure that you have $-$ in the denominator and not $+$. (check my last comment).

Comment: @Amr In the book it is that way - but as I said: it might be a misprint. Can you give me your idea for the modified (+) term?

Comment: ok I will put as answer

Comment: @mjb No. I know how to do it for $\frac{2^nx^{2^n}}{x^{2^n}+1}$. Let me think abt the original problem again

Comment: $\sum_1^1(1/(n(n+1)))$ is $1/2$, not $1$.

Comment: $x^{2^n}/(1-x^{2^n})$ is not a series. Please edit the title and the body so it asks what you really want to ask. Please don't rely on people wading through all the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [2-adic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) function $\nu_2$, one gets
$$
\frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^n}}=a_n(x)-a_{n+1}(x)$$ where $$a_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}b_n(k) x^k$$ with $$b_n(k)=(\nu_2(k)-n+1)\cdot\mathbf 1_{\nu_2(k)\geqslant n}
$$