# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^n}}$ when $x<1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Where does $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^n}}$ converges to (for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with x<1)?

Since we failed with the Ansatz [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270409/rewrite-series-fracx2n1-x2n-in-the-form-a-n-a-np-where-p), we were able to proof that the series diverges for $x>1$ and converges for $x<1$ by the ratio test. But we have no clue to which value it converges. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that $f(x) = f(x^2)+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni: Thank you, but this actually is $x^{(2^n)}$ and not $(x^2)^n$, as we would need in the Lambert series

Comment: @RaymondManzoni This is unrelated.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: Thank you, but I can't verify that. How would that help? What exactly is x?

Comment: @mjb To verify, simply plug in $x^2$ for $x$ and you will note that the $n$th summand turns into the original $(n+1)$st summand. Therefore, adding  the first summand back "repairs" this. Of course $x$ can be any number with $|x|<1$. You don't get an exact expression for $f(x)$, however.

Comment: Oups @did is right (I considered $2^n$ as $2n$ sorry...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> For every $|x|<1$, the sum of the series is $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2^n}}{1-x^{2^n}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\nu_2(n)x^n$$ where, for every nonzero integer $n$, $\nu_2(n)=\max\{k\geqslant0\mid n\in2^k\mathbb Z\}$ is the [2-adic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) of $n$.

To show this, expand each denominator as a geometric series with argument $x^{2^n}$. This yields the series as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}x^{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}x^{k2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}x^{k2^n}.
$$
Now, fix some $i\geqslant1$ and assume that $i=2^\nu j$ with $j$ odd. The term $x^i$ appears in the double sum on the RHS once for each factorization of $i$ as a product $(2^{\nu-1}j)\cdot2$, $(2^{\nu-2}j)\cdot2^2$, ..., and $j\cdot2^{\nu}$, that is, $\nu$ times.

This [generating function](http://oeis.org/A001511) has no simple form but the associated Dirichlet generating function is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\nu_2(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s)}{2^s-1}.
$$

Comment: Wow thank you - let me think about that a bit